# How to Login API to Identity Provider

Tags: api, authentication

Our system architecture has this setup. We have an API that is used by a WebApp Client. We allow users to authenticate using an Identity Provider (IDP) that returns SAML.

The problem is how would you setup authentication? Which of the flow below would be more suitable?

**WebApp Client controls the flow**

- When a user needing authentication visits WebApp Client, redirect user to IDP.
- User authenticates with IDP
- IDP redirect user back to webapp client with SAML response
- WebApp client passes the SAML to the API.
- The API will decrypt and read the attributes.
- API then gives access token to the WebApp client it can use for subsequent requests.

**API controls the flow**

- When a user needing authentication visits WebApp Client, redirect user to a special endpoint of API.
- API redirects user to IDP
- User authenticates with IDP
- IDP redirect user back to API with SAML response
- API decrypt and read the attributes
- API redirects user to the WebApp client passing an access token to the WebApp client it can use for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently asking myself the same questions with google idp. I thought about passing the returning code from idp to my API and then authenticating the user from my API.

If you have some return on your experience let me know :)